# Jenkins multi configuration passing parameters when running Maven job

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins multi configuration job for the selenium tests of my project that runs against multiple browsers. I checked the different options and the multi configuration job seems to be a good fit, but I cannot make maven pass the parameters correctly to maven.

I have a few parameters I need to pass to maven, mainly browserName and appDomain, and also a Profile to run the tests. To configure the job I do the following:

- Define the SVN repository from where the code will be checked out.
- Set up browserName as a user define axis, with values FIREFOX, CHROME, IE.
- Create a build step of type "Invoke top-level Maven targets", and here's where I get the problems. The configuration of this part is different from other job types, usually there's a field called Goals and Options where to put everything, but in this case is divided in different fields. So I don't know where exactly put the properties and the profile.

  a) The logical thing, I put the goals in Goals field and the parameters and options in the properties field, like in the image:

[image: first case]

In this case the job runs normally without executing the tests, because the profile is not executed.

b) If I put just the profile in the Goals field, the maven call in the log is:

```
/opt/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/mvn -DbrowserName=CHROME "-D-Dappdomain=0 -Dtestenv=test  -Drc=true -DsuiteXmlFile=testOne.xml -U -Dapp.instance.key=jenkins -Denv=default" clean verify -Pwebtests
```

And the exception is:

```
[INFO] [enforcer:enforce {execution: enforce-property}]
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty failed with message:
You must pass the appdomain as parameter! Example: -Dappdomain=20
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty failed with message:
You must pass the test environment as parameter! Example: -Dtestenv=beta
```

So is not getting the properties

c) Finally, if I put everything in the goals field, I get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] One or more required plugin parameters are invalid/missing for 'property:merge'

[0] Inside the definition for plugin 'property-maven-plugin' specify the following:

<configuration>
  ...
  <environment>VALUE</environment>
</configuration>
-OR-
on the command line, specify: '-Denv=VALUE'
```

I tried with a normal and parametrized job and works perfectly...

Jenkins version is: 1454 and Maven is 2.2.1

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin (i.e. have it installed)?

Comment: I think, but I'm not sure, I'll confirm tomorrow. But shouldn't it affect all job types? There are multiple jobs running the same maven goal and they work normally

Comment: It's just that I upgraded the plugin from v1.30 to the latest version and started having problems with matrix builds. I ended up downgrading it back. Chances are it's not connected to your problems, but worth checking (as your problems are also connected to setting the environment), unless you get a more definitive answer.

Comment: Confirmed, there's no EnvInject plugin... still scratching my head around this...

Comment: disabling? there is no EnvInject plugin installed

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment. Glad to see that you solved your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the Jenkins machine wasn't properly configured. I tried in another instance and was all good with the following configuration:

```
-Goals: clean verify Pwebtests
-Paramenters: (properties file format) 
appDomain=0 
testenv=test 
env=default
....
```

And as a sidenote, the other jobs were working because they were using the Jenkins Maven plugin, which seems to use java to launch a Hudson class that calls Maven, instead of calling directly the mvn command, which is what happens when a build step of type "Invoke top-level Maven Targets"